# ¿Cómo automatizar la obtención de un token que caduca pasado X tiempo?

Tags: angular, api, autenticación, backend, refreshtoken

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de Angular usando la API de Spotify y esta requiere que genere un token nuevo cada hora. Actualmente lo estoy haciendo de forma manual con Postman, usando mi usuario y clave de Spotify for developers para obtener un token que luego incluyo en el service de la web para obtener la data.

El caso es que se hace muy pesado estar cambiando cada hora el token y me preguntaba si hay alguna forma de automatizarlo usando back y de ser así, donde sería mejor subirlo de forma gratuita.

Además, necesito que esto me sirva para cuando suba el proyecto a producción para que la App funcione.

Nunca he usado back, por lo que agradecería mucho que me recomendáseis algún tutorial sencillo o una posible solución. Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Te recomiendo `expressjs`. Este es un tuto en espanol https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=794Q71KVw1k y este en ingles https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8uL0lFFoN0.

Comment: Despues te lees esto: https://medium.com/@asfo/autenticando-un-api-rest-con-nodejs-y-jwt-json-web-tokens-5f3674aba50e. Que tal vez no es la solucion, pero para que entiendas como funciona la api con el token. Y hagas algun middleware para renovar el token.

Comment: Lo suyo es que cuando obtienes un token, obtengas también la fecha de caducidad y un token de renovación. Así, antes de utilizarlo, válidas si ha caducado, y si es así renuevas con el token de renovacion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola angela te recomendaria que el refresh token lo valides en el back cuando realizes una petición y utilizar un interceptor para validar si el token caduco y volver a generarlo desde el front y asi nuevamente enviar la actualización del token y continuar el proceso que estabas realizando.

Si es necesario que se ejecute obligatoriamente cada hora podrias hacer algo asi

```
const newDate = new Date();
const tokenTime = (expirationDate as any) - (newDate as any);
timer(tokenTime).subscribe(
   () => {
//Aca internamente realizas el proceso que necesitas 
})
```

(el expirationDate) seria el tiempo necesario para completar el timer.

Esto es con Rxjs podrias echarle un ojo seguro te servira en muchas cosas.